# UILocalNotification : updating BadgeNumber during repeatInterval

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification

After goggling for 2 days i couldn't find any solution as if its clear to everyone (but me) !

I need the:

```
Alert.applicationIconBadgeNumber = x
```

to be updated in background each time the notification fires, I am repeating the notify by:

```
notif.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit
```

Repeating is working fine every 1 m. when the app goes in background, but the BadgeNumber dosent get updated, it takes the 1st updated date value only.

I am calling the scheduleNotification method by viewDidLoad

### Here is my full code:

```
- (void)scheduleNotification {
UILocalNotification *notif;
notif = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease];
notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notif.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:5];
notif.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit; 

NSInteger BadgeNumber = [self BadgeNumber];
NSInteger *BadgeNumberPointer = &BadgeNumber;
NSString *BadgeNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", BadgeNumber];

notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = *BadgeNumberPointer;

notif.alertBody = BadgeNumberString;
notif.alertAction = @"Hello";

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
}

-(int)BadgeNumber{
NSDate *currentDateUpdate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter2 setDateFormat:@"dd"];
NSString *dateCheckUpdate = [formatter2 stringFromDate:currentDateUpdate];
NSInteger dateCheckUpdateInt = [[dateCheckUpdate substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)] integerValue];

int BadgeNumber = dateCheckUpdateInt;
return BadgeNumber;
}
```

Kindly advice how to fix it,, thanking all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the operating system copies the notification when scheduled, the data in the notification is not updated, therefore the application badge number doesn't change.

Maybe if you don't repeat the notification but generate your own new notification for each time interval it will give you the behavior you need.  The only way I can think of generating notifications like that is to post a bunch of notifications in your scheduleNotification method, and then remember to delete the notifications when the user responds in the proper way.  Since the OS only remembers the next chronologically scheduled 64 notifications, you could only schedule about an hour's worth.  Since your badge number seems to be the current date, you could check the time and only bother with setting so many notifications if you're within an hour of midnight.

I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish by nagging the user so often, nor telling them the date in the badge number. Any app that bothered me so much or misused the badge number so would quickly get deleted from my iOS devices.  Maybe rethinking what you are trying to accomplish may direct you to a better solution.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Berna, but while being in background, i cant generate new notification on time basis. I tried using NSTimer but its not being called within (applicationDidEnterBackground). Any suggestion what to do?

Comment: Thank you again my friend for your time,, i think your suggestion is the only way to do it, I will give it a try. About your comments: the minute notify is just for test purpose, the final notify will be daily. Also I would like to thank you for driving my attention to the 64 not. issue, its what i was looking for as well. thx again.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is already answered, but you could use NSUserDefaults as a means of caching the badge count. Then in `applicationIconBadgeNumber` you can just use something like this:

```
notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = ([NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"badgeCount"] + 1);
```

and then you could just reset it when the user responds accordingly.

Comment: Can you write some code lines plz? I tried your solution but didn't work.

Comment: @hafedh Sure, I'll be glad to help, but could you please open a new question with specific details about what you're trying to do, and then post the link here?

Comment: Thanks a lot, here is all : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985409/xcode-use-local-notification-to-update-icon-badge-daily