# UILocalNotification repeatInterval + applicationIconBadgeNumber

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to schedule repeating local notifications and set the application badge number to the actual number of notifications that have been scheduled so far at any given moment.

Since there's apparently no way to set a different badge number for each occurrence of the notification, I can see only 3 solutions:

- Ignore the `repeatInterval` property of the notification and schedule separate notifications myself (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734464/uilocalnotification-updating-badgenumber-during-repeatinterval)). The thing is, since the system holds only 64 notifications per application, I may miss notifications if the user taps "dismiss" too many times, especially if several notifications are active.
- Show an incorrect badge number (1 for each unique notification, regardless of the number of times this notification has been repeated so far).
- Not use a badge at all.

Am I missing something, or are these the only 3 options?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like those are your options, since the badge number property of an `UILocalNotification` does not increment the current `applicationIconBadgeNumber` but just set it's these are your options.

Also keep in mind that when going with option 1 your have a maximum of 64 notifications that can be set, but you know that already ;)